# Registering iap purchase analytics event in Flutter using Flurry analytics

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, flurry, flurry-analytics

I am new to Flurry analytics, and from the looks of the docs they have for both [iOS](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/revenue/ios/) and [Android](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/revenue/android/), there is a support for registering purchase events with a dedicated method on each platform separately. But with [flutter plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flurry) they have, this option is not supported, and therefore I am not able to register purchases at all on their dashboard. Is there a way of "manually" sending this iap event, so the dashboard can still consume it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking if this data can be sent directly to the Flurry servers, without being sent from the SDK. If so, this is unfortunately not possible.

Comment: Is there a way that developer on your end can help out in basically updating the Flutter package? At least to get me up to speed with iOS / Android specifics of the package regarding purchase making...

Comment: The plugin is made by a third party developer, rather than directly from Flurry. They would need to manage any updates.